# Counting columns null and not null in PostgreSql

Tags: database, postgresql

I need count columns that has null values and not null values for each row,
but i don't have idea of how i can do this in PostgreSql.

Comment: Make your question clear.

Comment: @tchelidze you can better understand ?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to specify the column name in the count(), it will skip the null:s

```
select avg(c),count(c) from (select generate_series(1,10) union select null) as a(c);
```

Ignore the stuff after from, it's just to return a list of values

To make it more clear:

```
select
  avg(c),
  count(c) count_column,
  count(*) count_star,
  sum(c),
  array_agg(c)
from (
  select generate_series(1,10) union select null order by 1
) as a(c);

        avg         | count_column | count_star | sum |          array_agg          
--------------------+--------------+------------+-----+-----------------------------
 5.5000000000000000 |           10 |         11 |  55 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,NULL}
(1 row)
```

Comment: how can add my select from table in this query ? i tried change from select null to select columnsName from table, and not working.

Comment: select count(column_name), avg(column_name) from table_name

Comment: but this " 
select count(column_name), avg(column_name) from table_name" is in with union in select generate_series not ? i don't understand where my select table enters it.

Comment: You don't need the generate series stuff at all,  select count(column_name), avg(column_name) from table_name is the complete query

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean.Please add your table to the question and the query you are trying with. Also an example of what output you want

Comment: Example:

table posts(
 - id 
 - title
 - body
 - type
);

and the query would be something like:

"select count(columnsNULL) as columnsNull, count(ColumnsNotNull) from posts"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm tryng calculate percentage of post filled according to the columns filled in database.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countNullRows FROM yourTable WHERE columnName IS NULL;
SELECT COUNT(*) as countNonNullRows FROM yourTable WHERE columnName IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: rowName is name of each column ??

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant to write columnName (editing the answer)... It's name of the column you're checking whether it has null or non-null value.

Comment: but is more than one columns, i'll have to add one each one column in my where clause ?

Comment: You don't need the WHERE, just count(columnName), it will skip the NULL:s

Comment: but he is counting all lines and not for each line. 

i tried this  " SELECT COUNT(*) as countNullRows, * FROM posts group by id "